# Find increase in history records in specific range

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I want to find records in date range 1/1/19-1/7/19 which increase amount

using table `HISTORY`:

> DATE AMOUNT ID

(Date, number, varchar2(30))

I find IDs inside range correctly

assuming increase/decrease can happens only when having two records with same Id

```
 with suspect as
 (select id
    from history
   where t.createddate < to_date('2019-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
   group by id
  having count(1) > 1),
ids as
 (select id
    from history
    join suspect
      on history.id = suspect.id
   where history.date > to_date('2019-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
     and history.date < to_date('2019-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
select count(distinct id)
  from history a, history b
 where a.id = b.id
   and a.date < b.date
   and a.amount < b.amount
```

The problem to find increase I need to find **previous record** which can be before time range

I can find last previous time before time range, but I failed to use it:

```
ids_prevtime as (
  select history.*, max(t.date) over (partition by t.id) max_date
  from history   
  join ids on history.userid = ids.id
   where history.date < to_date('2019-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd' )  
  ), ids_prev as (
  select * from ids_prevtime where createdate=max_date
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you found solution, but maybe you could do it simpler, using `lag()`:

```
select count(distinct id)
  from (select id, date_, amount, 
               lag(amount) over (partition by id order by date_) prev_amt
          from history)
  where date_ between date '2019-01-01' and date '2019-07-01' 
    and amount > prev_amt;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=996fa6e648a42f1ad38ef3fd0f117a37)</sup>**

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, Is using analytic function (as lag) always bad for performance?

Comment: @user7294900 . . . Analytic functions usually perform better than alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Add union of last history records before range with records inside range

```
ids_prev as
 (select ID, DATE, AMOUNT
    from id_before_rangetime
   where createddate = max_date),
ids_in_range as
 (select history.*
    from history
    join ids
      on history.ID = ids.ID
   where history.date > to_date('2019-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
     and history.date < to_date('2019-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')),
all_relevant as
 (select * from ids_in_range union all select * from ids_prev)
```

and then count increases:

```
select count(distinct id)
  from all_relevant a, all_relevant b
 where a.id = b.id
   and a.date < b.date
   and a.amount < b.amount
```